# Dynamically update gauge on highcharts

Tags: jquery, dynamic, charts, highcharts, gauge

I'm working in a university website project, and I choose to work with Highcharts, it has a very easy usage. But i'm having some problems to work with `.getjson` for dynamically update.

I used this http://www.highcharts.com/studies/live-server.htm, and this http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/zpwdp/ samples.
And I havenn't got any success. Then i try to learn by my own on the API, and i came to this:

```
function requestData() {
    $.jQuery.getJSON('values.php', data, 
        function(){
            var series = chart.series[0]
            chart.series.update()
            setTimeout(requestData, 1000);  
        }
)}
```

I left the data values on the chart empty, and i loaded `requestData` on the file, but it still don't work.
Can someone help me?
Sorry for my english.
Thanks!

Comment: How your json/ data looks like?

Comment: The data is just a number, php returns me exactly that: [200]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Refer this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/tDqp2/):

```
var new_value = 160;
var point = $('#container').highcharts().series[0].points[0];       
point.update(new_value);
```

According to your case, it should be like:

```
function requestData() {
    $.jQuery.getJSON('values.php', data, 
        function(){
            var new_value = 160;//the value you wish to update and set to guage
            var point = $('#div_id_of_chart_rendering').highcharts().series[0].points[0];       
            point.update(new_value);  
        }
)}
```

Comment: The function that update the chart should be inside the chart? I was calling another function inside the chart with an event.

Answer (score 0):

When your data object is returned, you need to put that data into the chart series. At the moment, you aren't doing anything with your data object. The relevent highcharts API call is 'setData' (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.setData).

You will need to do something like:

```
function requestData() {
$.jQuery.getJSON('values.php', data, 
    function(){
        chart.series.setData(data)
        setTimeout(requestData, 1000);  
    }
)}
```

For this to work, your php needs to return a valid series data object (e.g. an array of points).

Comment: Before I was setting the data from values.php directly to the chart. It was working, it gives me just one value, for example: [210].
I've tried what you said, but it still don't work. It seems me that the data isn't going to the chart. The chart don't show any value.
Should I set a variable or something like that on the series of the chart?